# Why is my puppie's tooth gray?

Tags: dogs, health, diet, dental-care

I noticed that my puppy Angie (3 months) has a little gray tooth. I don't give her candies or sweet food, I just feed her milk powder and croquettes for puppies.

Why does she have a gray tooth?

Is that a cavity? Or is it normal?

Finally I could get the photo:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the tip of the tooth has broken off and it has been infected.

Take your dog to a vet and get the tooth extracted, so it doesn't makes problems when the permanent tooth apears in a few months.

Comment: that sounds very painful for my puppy

Comment: yes it is painful,there is some swelling of the gum too so it is best to have the tooth removed.

Comment: I'll take her to the vet and we'll see what happens, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Although extraction is painful, your pup may already be hurting and it will be what's best to keep the Infection from spreading. The tissue under the tooth has necrotized (hense the coloring), and you don't want that Infection or dead tissue spreading to it's gums or blood stream... Blood stream infections can lead to many other issues in the body. Glad to hear you'll take him to the vet, he'll feel much better after. Great, simple answer, and to the point @trondhansen

Comment: @ChristyB. the vet said that the tooth will be removed by it's own soon. If it doesn't then he will remove it the next month (november). Should I tell the vet to remove it now??  your comment it's kinda alarming

Comment: Did the vet examine him?

Comment: @ChristyB. yes, he even touch her tooth and he said 'the tooth is hard/stiff'

Comment: I'm looking closer at the pic and it appears that the gums do not look inflamed or swollen. A good sign (but not 100% accurate sign) that an Infection has not spread to gums. You may very well have time, but being that the tooth has not loosened yet, it may be a while before the tooth falls out on it's own. Just something to consider. If too much time goes by and your pup is in constant pain, or the gums start to look worse, or it starts to produce an odor or rank breath, and/or he stops eating due to discomfort, go ahead and quickly have it extracted.

Comment: @ChristyB. alright, thanks for your advices, I appreciated :). As a side note, she eats a **lot** of food and she wants constantly bite things (whatever she finds, she destroys it)